# Regarding Angular PrimeNG table formArray

Tags: html, angular, typescript, frontend, primeng

I am trying to create the PrimeNg editable table with angular forms. I don't understand how to use formArray. I tried so many times but I was struck with formGroupName error.

[This is current behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvCtD.png)

※ Actual behavior ⇒ only touched and invalid component(Input field) border should output in red color.

※ I think here we should use formArray to check the validation.

※ Add Row button in another component.

**HTML**

```
<p-table [loading]="loading" styleClass="text-sm " [ngClass]="{'p-datatable-is-loading': loading}" [value]="dataSource"
  [scrollable]="true" scrollHeight="calc(100% + 2px)" scrollDirection="both">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 250px;">Project</th>
      <th style="width: 250px;">Process</th>
      <th style="width: 200px;">Working Hours</th>
      <th style="width: 168px;">Billed To</th>
      <th style="width: 350px;">What did you work on?</th>
      <th style="width: 350px;">Blockers</th>
      <th alignFrozen="right" pFrozenColumn class="p-frozen-column p-frozen-border-left" style="width: 114px;"></th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" [formGroup]="_formHelper.form" let-source let-index="rowIndex">
    <tr *ngIf="dataSource[index].editing; else viewingMode;" class="editing editing-mode">
      <td style="width: 250px; overflow: visible">
        
<p-autoComplete  appendTo="body" #project name="project" [(ngModel)]="dataSource[index].project_id" [suggestions]="projectSuggestions"
          field="name" (onSelect)="handleSelectProject($event, index)"
          (onBlur)="_formHelper.validateControl('project')" formControlName="project"
          (completeMethod)="handleSearchProject($event, index)" (onFocus)="project.show()" placeholder="Search project">
        </p-autoComplete>

      </td>
      
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

**TS**

```
export class DailyReportRegularTableComponent extends DailyReportLog implements OnInit {

  helper!: HelperService
  _formHelper: FormService = new FormService;
  _model: UIProjectLogForm = {
    id:  '',
    process:  '',
    minutes:  undefined,
    hour:  undefined,
    work_note:  '',
    blocker_note:  '',
    daily_time_log_id:  '',
    billed_to:  '',
    project_id:  '',
    project_name:  '',
  };

  constructor(private _helper: HelperService,private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    super();
    this.helper = this._helper;
    this.initForm();
  }
  
  initForm() {
    this._formHelper.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      project: new FormControl(this._model.project_id, {
        validators: Validators.required,
        updateOn: 'blur'
      })
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: So when do you want validation to work ?

Comment: Please provide code in stackblitz or similar platform

Comment: 1) I think your StackBlitz did not take. 2) **_formHelper: FormService = new FormService;** should be **new FormService();**.  3) Services should be injected via the constructor. 4) I strongly suggest using **strict**, it would of flagged **new FormService;** and you are loosing the benefits of TypeScript.

Comment: thank you @PhilHuhn can you show me the example via stackblitz?

Comment: I have never used reactive forms with turbotable (p-table).  I just was pointing out things that might help.